# he walked across to the house

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I found this sentence:

> He stopped for a moment, then walked across to the house.

I can't understand the meaning of "across" and the use of "to the".

The context: a man ("he") is hiding in the garden of a house and the owner of the house call him in whispering.

Comment: Note that this is from a very poorly-written "paraphrase" of a great work of English literature called _War of the Worlds_ by H.G. Wells. The original, and properly-written, sentence is : _"Then he came over and across **the lawn** to the corner of the house."_ I highly recommend reading the real novel, which is available at no charge at **[Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/36/36-h/36-h.htm)**. ( @Catija n.b.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'll certainly read the original. At the moment I'm still learning by listening to readed novels (so I can hear the right pronunciation).

Comment: If this is an example, the writing is very poor indeed. You can easily find a reading of the _real_ novel, in its original version, and I encourage you to do so.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm not sure of it, but it's possible that the writing was simplified to make it easier to an English learner. Don't you think is so?

Comment: That may have been their intention, but here they took a perfectly simple, good, and understandable sentence and made it into something that is _harder_ to understand. There is nothing difficult in the real _War of the Worlds._

Comment: @P.E.Dant You have a great deal of knowledge and yet so rarely actually use it to answer a question... please, don't leave it all in comments, free for deletion at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an acceptable sentence, when it says "across" it's leaving you to mentally insert what he walked across. So, the full version of the sentence would actually read something like:

> He stopped for a moment, then walked across [the lawn/yard] to the house.

With this added detail, I hope it becomes clear what was occurring in this situation.

Comment: Note that Wells's original sentence made the action quite clear!

Answer (score 0):

The preposition **across** functions to show the **direction** of a **movement** from one area **(= garden)** to another area **(=house)**.

The preposition **to** is used to show or indicate the destination (of a verb). 
Its a short word that points to the destination. (sorry, that is not very technical, but I hope you understand)

The article **the** is used to refer to a specific place that both the speaker and listener are aware of. (or the house could be the only house in the area).

I hope that helps you.

Some help from The Ins and Outs of Prepositions by Jean Yates Ph.D.